# Составить mysql запрос для выборки значений

Tags: sql

[image: структура]

Как можно выбрать page_id(сгруппированные) у которых в page_type_id есть значение 3, но нет 2

Answer (score 1):

Как-то вроде так:

```
select p1.page_id from page_additional_info p1
where p1.page_type_id=2
and not exists (select * from page_additional_info p2 
where p1.page_info=p2.page_info and p2.page_type_id=3)
group by p1.page_id
```

Comment: Лучше не GROUP BY, а DISTINCT. Ну и SELECT * в подзапросе можно заменить на литерал какой - а то привыкнет ведь...

Comment: @Akina Я не настоящий db-шник, я просто мимо проходил )  Хотел написать `distinct`, но просили же `group by`. А насчёт подзапроса - в смысле `1`, например, вместо `*`? Мне кажется я читал исследования, что разницы нет, а иногда так вроде даже хуже. Но не уверен, конечно. И зависит от того, что за база.

Comment: *Мне кажется я читал исследования, что разницы нет* Для NOT EXISTS да, разницы почти нет (за исключением случаев, когда структура таблицы пухлая - тогда разница таки есть). А вот в случае WHERE EXISTS разница реально есть.  *а иногда так вроде даже хуже* Вот даже представить не могу причин подобного... разве что некорректный эксперимент мог дать подобный эффект. Непрогретый кэш, не проконтролированы планы выполнения и т.п.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо за подсказки, удалось решить так

```
SELECT page_id, page_type_id FROM page_additional_info
WHERE page_id NOT IN (SELECT page_id FROM page_additional_info where page_type_id = 2)
AND page_type_id = 3
GROUP BY page_id
```